# Why doesn't intellisense recognize my extension method?

Tags: flutter, dart

I wrote a extension method for the get package so that I can put my dependencies in my build methods without having to worry that they get registered more then once

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';

extension on Get{
  static T putIfNotRegistered<T>(T dependency, {bool find = false})
  {
    if(!Get.isRegistred<T>())
      return Get.put(dependency);
    if(find)
      return Get.find<T>();
    return null;
  }
}
```

But when I try to use it, it says that it cannot find the method putIfNotRegistered on Get? I have the extention method in a file called extension_methods.dart and I am trying to find it in the main.dart. I imported the extension_methods.dart. So what do I need to do to get my extension method working?

The error reads

```
The method 'putIfNotRegistered' isn't defined for the type 'Get'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'putIfNotRegistered'.
```

When I try to use it in my main.dart

```
Get.putIfNotRegistered<DatabaseService>(FirestoreService(authenticationService.user));
```

Comment: Give your extension a name like `extension AnyName on Get`

Comment: O... that fixed it. Didn't realize you had to give a name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to use your extension method outside a file where you declared it, you must give it a name.

```
extension AnyName on Get
```

should fix your issue.